# squelching glibc memory corruption stack trace output

Tags: c, glibc

Is there any way to squelch the output that glibc generates when there is memory corruption? Here's what I'm seeing

```
make
*** glibc detected *** /home/myname/php/sapi/cli/php: free(): invalid pointer:  x0045d67f ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/libc.so.6(+0x6eb41)[0x380b41]

<snip>
======= Memory map: ========
00115000-00116000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
001d7000-001ee000 r-xp 00000000 ca:01 540738     /lib/libpthread-2.12.2.so
001ee000-001ef000 r--p 00016000 ca:01 540738     /lib/libpthread-2.12.2.so
001ef000-001f0000 rw-p 00017000 ca:01 540738     /lib/libpthread-2.12.2.so
<snip>
```

For the work I am doing, I couldn't care less about this info, it only matters that the make did not succeed (return value != 0). These messages are filling up the screen and it makes the rest of my output unreadable. I have tried:

```
make &> /dev/null
{ make ; } &> /dev/null
x=`make 2>&1` &> /dev/null
```

but none of them catch the output. If it isn't being written to stderr, where the heck is it coming from? I'd like a solution that doesn't require rebuilding glibc, if possible.

Here is some code which will give such an error message, but note this has nothing to do with the code I am working on (the php source code). I just want to silence this type of output from my console.

```
int main()
{
    char* ptr = (char*)malloc(sizeof("test"));
    char array[]= "test";
    ptr = array;
    free(ptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps it's writing to stdin? (If fd 0 refers to your tty, there is nothing that prevents a process from writing to it). Or for that matter just to `/dev/tty`, the idea being that you really want to see this. (+1 for using "couldn't care less" correctly; -1 for not caring -- it evens out). If everything else fails, grab the glibc source and grep through it for the text of the message.

Comment: The best way to squelch it would be to fix the memory corruption. Even if you recompiled glibc with the code to print the trace disabled, Joe Blackhat could have your program happily printing stack traces again with the right shellcode... ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes: run your code with the environment variable `MALLOC_CHECK_` (the trailing underscore is deliberate) set to `0`.

This is [partially documented in the libc manual](http://www.gnu.org/s/hello/manual/libc/Heap-Consistency-Checking.html), although there seem to be more options than just the `0`, `1` or `2` which are suggested there.  (The value ends up being passed as the `action` argument to `malloc_printerr()` in glibc's [`malloc/malloc.c`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=dccb6cc4fd0f87f74870b37e780bef04b1ae48a0;hb=356f8bc660a154a07b03da7c536831da5c8f74fe#l6269), and [the default value seems to be `3`](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c;h=dccb6cc4fd0f87f74870b37e780bef04b1ae48a0;hb=356f8bc660a154a07b03da7c536831da5c8f74fe#l2551).)

The reason you can't redirect it is that it gets written specifically to `/dev/tty`, unless you have set the environment variable `LIBC_FATAL_STDERR_`.  (I'm not sure this is documented anywhere, but the relevant code can be found [here](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/libc_fatal.c;h=e1b4c8d314dcc80dd227721062c43f7564b31ade;hb=356f8bc660a154a07b03da7c536831da5c8f74fe#l51).)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much. I was looking at __write and that was getting me nowhere. This worked like a charm.